# how can i resolve error 23505 on pgadmin?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert, pgadmin

I created a table named "Seats";

```
CREATE TABLE Seats
  (id              serial PRIMARY KEY,
   line            text  NOT NULL ,
   screeningroom   text NOT NULL,
   seatnumber      text NOT NULL
);
```

after that i tried an INSERT Script which gave me:

```
INSERT INTO public.seats(
    id, line, screeningroom, seatnumber)
    VALUES (?,?, ?, ?);
```

inside values i put

```
VALUES (1,'a', 1, 1);
```

and it gave me a SQL STATE error 23505:
ERROR: A violation of the constraint imposed by a unique index or a unique constraint occurred.
DETAIL: key (id) =(1) already exists.

can anybody tell me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Do not input a value into a `serial` column.  It is defined as serial so the database can increment it for you:

```
INSERT INTO public.seats (line, screeningroom, seatnumber)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

Comment: but i need that serial value, i can't delete it

Comment: @ElenaCiuffreda . . . This doesn't *delete* it; it sets it automatically.  If you need to insert the value, then just declare it as an `int` -- and take care to deal with duplicates using `on conflict`.

Comment: now it gives me another error; sql state 42601 --> INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Comment: @ElenaCiuffreda . . . In this answer, there are three parameters and three columns.  The numbers match.